# Update mysql on NodejJS

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, sql-update

I have a form that I want to edit and save on my data base.

In fact when a user want to edit this information, I don't know what variable that he changed.

How I can edit my data base without to use all variables (name, adress) in the UPDATE? If that it's possible.

```
UPDATE client SET *name = ?, adress = ? ...* WHERE id = ?";
```

Thank you

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for an alternative to the classic:

`"UPDATE client SET name = ?, adress = ? ... WHERE id = ?", [name_var,address_var,id_var], function......` , 
just stick to that way of passing variables to an update query and you'll be just fine. But please read the [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) prior to asking questions.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer and I will read the community guidelines.